# Can I make all public variables/methods/classes internal in Visual Studio at compile time?

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, public, internal

I would like to make all my public variables variables/methods/classes internal when compiling my Visual Studio project. The source code would not change but when the compiled library is done, it should only have internal access. Is this possible?

I have "InternalsVisibleTo("ClassLibrary") " set inthe Assembly info file for all the projects, however, I would not like to run a replace all on "public " to "internal ". Does anyone know if there is away around this? So when I compile, build my project, the release project is only allowing internal access.

Thank you and have a nice day,

Joe

Comment: Is there a particular reason you do not want to just declare your types and members as `internal`?

Comment: I don't understand. If every single member is `internal`, how will outside code use the library?

Comment: By using the InternalsVisibleTo() in the assembly info file.

Comment: I wanna keep them internal as I want the types and members to only be accessible within the same assembly.

Comment: So declare them as internal instead of public then, what's the problem?

Comment: " I would not like to run a replace all on "public " to "internal " That is why, it is like several thousands of replacements. I was just wondering if there was a way to do this automatically with a flag at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the use of the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. It is used to allow code in *another* assembly to access types and members declared as `internal`.

Say you have AssemblyA, in which you have `internal class SomeClass`. Then you have AssemblyB. The code in AssemblyB cannot use `SomeClass`, since it is `internal` in AssemblyA. You can then, in AssemblyA, use `InternalsVisibleTo` to grant access for AssemblyB to use the `internal` types and members of AssemblyA.

If you simply want to make the code internal to AssemblyA, you will need to declare the types accordingly from the start; there are no shortcuts for that.